# convert pandas dataframe with None;s in it to spark dataframe

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do I convert pandas data frame with few None's in it to pyspark dataframe?

Pandas Dataframe  -pandas_df :

```
0    30832
1      859
2     None
3    11982
4     None
5    18218
6    21232
7    26804
8    25144
9    15921
```

creating schema like below - mySchema:

```
StructField("column_count", LongType(), True)
```

applying schema:

```
spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df, mySchema)
```

> Error : TypeError: field term_ins_year_cnt: LongType can not accept
> object 30832.0 in type <class 'float'>

Answer (score 2):

You can use a float type column to convert, and cast to long type in Spark:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, FloatType
import pandas as pd

pandas_df = pd.DataFrame([11,22,33,33,None], columns = ['col'])

mySchema = StructType([StructField("column_count", FloatType(), True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df, mySchema) \
     .replace(float('nan'), None) \
     .withColumn("column_count", F.col("column_count").cast("long"))

df.show()
+------------+
|column_count|
+------------+
|          11|
|          22|
|          33|
|          33|
|        null|
+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This will it take care of "None"?

Comment: if 'None' is not there in df it works fine.

Comment: Yes, it should take care of None. I guess pandas do not have nullable integer type, so it represents internally as float, so you need to specify float type when converting to spark.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts. But it's not working.             
data = [ 11,22,33,33,None] # Fails
            #data = [ 11,22,33,33,55] # Success
            df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['col']) 
            df = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
           
            print(df["col"])
            df.info()
            
            struct_list = []
            struct_list.append(StructField("col", LongType(), True))
            mySchema = StructType(struct_list)
            
            df = self.spark.createDataFrame(df, mySchema).withColumn("col", df.col("col").cast("long"))

Comment: @Sachin you can't use `df.col("col")` in the initialization of `df` because `df` has not yet been initialized. Please use `F.col` instead. `F` comes from `import pyspark.sql.functions as F`. See my edited answer.

Comment: It ends up with a similar error in the original question. As mentioned earlier, if we take out "None' from the df, i.e. data = [ 11,22,33,33,55] all works well. Thanks for showing interest.

Comment: @Sachin please show the complete error traceback along with the code you used, by editing your question to include those details. It’s very hard to debug without any details.

Comment: @Sachin could you try the complete code in my edited answer, and see if it works for you?